# Ruby - Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby, rubygems, redmine, puppet, i18n-gem

I'm trying to install Redmine, but I'm in trouble on the final steps.
I never used a Ruby environment before, I'm a complete beginner.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

(bundle install in not helping.)
So I tried to 'gem install i18n -v 0.6.1', telling me '1 gem installed' and everything ok.

And it still doesn't work, and still don't get i18n (in any version) when I 'gem list'

The previous answer doesn't fix anything for me, I'm not using passenger.

Thanks.

EDIT : I found the dir where my gems are, /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems
in18-0.6.1 and other gems are here, but not listed in 'gem list'

EDIT 2 : Ok, my problem is more precise now. I'm actually trying to write a puppet script to install Redmine, and the 'bundle install' is actually working on a command line, but not in an exec puppet resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have problem with installing gems on remote and have not frequently updated project, you can cache gems and add them to git by  `bundle package` and installing them after by
`bundle install --local`